# bootstrap4 3 columns large, 2 columns medium, 1 column small

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have multiple rows with 3 columns at the largest breakpoint, 2 columns at medium, and one column at small. But at the medium breakpoint, that third column is appearing in it's own row. How can I get a kind of wrapping effect so that the third column from the first row and the first column from the second row appear side by side in a row at the medium breakpoint? Does it have to do with flexbox? I don't know flexbox too well. Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">one</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">two</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">three</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">one</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">two</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">three</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So I want this to look like:

LARGE:
one two three
one two three

MEDIUM:
one two
three one
two three

SMALL:
one
two
three
one
two
three

My problem is with the medium breakpoint

Answer (score 2):

please try this following code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">one</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">two</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">three</div>     
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">one</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">two</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">three</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Grid layout in Bootstrap sums up to 12. As you have 3 divs, try: `col-md-4` instead of `col-md-6`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: ii medium he wants 2 box in one row so col-md-6 is valid. and remove second-row div.

Answer (score 1):

[Read the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/). There is no `-xs` in Bootstrap 4.

- keep all the col in a single `.row`.
- use `col-lg-4` for 3 columns across on lg.
- there's no reason to use `col-12` because it's implied on xs screens.

---

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">one</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">two</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">three</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">one</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">two</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/quk8RRLANG